# How to make a switch from circle to square shapes? -SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a game, where the player is tapping for circles, and I want the player to tap on the square instead of circles.

Here is my code for only tapping circles

```
override func addBall(_ size: Int) {
    let currentBall = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(size))
    let shape = SKShapeNode()
    let viewMidX = view!.bounds.midX
    let viewMidY = view!.bounds.midY

    currentBall.fillColor = pickColor()

    //Rectangle
    shape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 64, y: 64, width: 160, height: 160), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath

    shape.fillColor = pickColor()

    func randomBallPosition() -> CGPoint {
        let xPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxX)! + 1)))
        let yPosition = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(UInt32((view?.bounds.maxY)! + 1)))

        return CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
    }

    currentBall.position = randomBallPosition()
    shape.position = randomBallPosition()

    self.addChild(shape)

    //Remove other balls and add the new one
    if scoreCount != 0{
        if scoreCount == 1{
            self.addChild(score)
            self.addChild(timeLeftLabel)
            self.childNode(withName: "welcome")?.removeFromParent()
        }
        self.childNode(withName: "ball")?.run(getSmaller)
        self.childNode(withName: "ball")?.removeFromParent()
    }
    currentBall.name = "ball"

    self.addChild(currentBall)
}
```

Comment: SpriteKit is tricky, but with a little help from the docs you can pull off exactly what you are thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: )`

instead of `SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius:)`

rest of your code will work fine.

EDIT:

You also wanna use `UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect)` instead of `init(roundedRect: CGRect, cornerRadius: CGFloat)`

Comment: So, should I put  let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGFloat(size))?

Comment: Yes please give it a try. And let me know if it works.

Comment: it says "Cannot convert value of type CGFloat to expected argument type CGSize'

Comment: @Jonathon don't ask such basic question, read docs. If it needs CGSize then provide a CGSize. A rectangle is described with two values, not one.

Comment: when doing:   let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(dictionaryRepresentation: size as! CFDictionary)!) it crashes the app point  to: func addBall(_ size: Int) .

Comment: let shape = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width:CGFloat(size), height:CGFloat(size)))